# tmux status bar is breaking

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, tmux

Yesterday, I added https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux this to my tmux. I was able to use it correctly. Unfortunately,it started breaking today with this error, and the status bar keeps appearing in random places. I tried searching for this error but couldn't find it.

How can I solve this? I'm using termius for Android, it worked yesterday. Works fine on the computer itself, but not over SSH in Android. Couldn't test in other cases

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Are you using Ubuntu? Where? We cannot help you with Android issues. In any case, this sounds like something you should ask of the developers of this tool. Have you opened a github issue?

Comment: @terdon SSH = Secure Shell; so, they're connecting remotely to the machine from their Android using the app [Termius](https://termius.com/free-ssh-client-for-android), an Android SSH client. While it is noticed on the Android side it's likely caused by Ubuntu itself. Most likely the troubleshooting fix from the Readme, as mentioned in the answer I posted.

Comment: @l3l_aze yes, thank you, I am familiar with ssh. It wasn't clear, however, where the error was occurring, or if the OP was connecting from an Ubuntu machine to Android (off topic) or from Android to Ubuntu (on topic).

Answer (score 0):

There's a troubleshooting section in the Readme that starts just below the install directions. More specifically it includes, "Status line is broken and/or gets duplicated at the bottom of the screen. What gives?".

Their suggestion is to not use "Unicode characters for which width changed in between Unicode 8.0 and 9.0 standards, as well as Emojis" in the `...../tmux.conf.local` that you install (copy).